# Simple java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java

So I am trying to create a main menu for my java 2d game. I was thinking of using a cardlayout to swap between the main menu and the game itself. But I didn't get that far before running into this error. I was trying to draw the background image for the title screen, but this error occurred. Let me just refer the two classes.

First class, loads the JFrame and card layout:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainScreen extends JFrame{

    public static CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();//set a new cardlayout

    // *** JPanel to hold the "cards" and to use the CardLayout:
    static JPanel cardContainer = new JPanel(cardLayout);//some variable for the cardlayout
    public static JComboBox cardCombo = new JComboBox();//some variable for the cardlayout
    public static JPanel comboPanel = new JPanel();;//some variable for the cardlayout

    public MainScreen() {

        setTitle("Project");//Title of the screen
        setSize(800,600);//Size of the window
        setResizable(false);//Is the window resizable?
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//Exit the frame when the default red cross is clicked
        setVisible(true);//is the frame visible?
        getContentPane().add(cardContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);//add the cardcontainer to flip panels
    }

public static void debug(){//makes an extra card, this is a debug card and is not used for anything but debugging

        JPanel debugPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());//Debug panel, not used for anything, script does not work if not here
        debugPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);//set the background color to black
        String debug = "Debug Panel";//name the card or something like that
        cardContainer.add(debugPanel, debug);//add the card to the panel
        cardCombo.addItem(debug);//add the item??
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){//this runs when the script opens

        new MainScreen();//run the main screen class, that loads the window and card layout
        debug();//run the next class that initializes the mainmenu
        new MainMenu();//load the main menu
    }
}
```

Class that loads the menu screen and tries to draw the background image:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MainMenu extends JComponent{

    Image background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("data/images/title.png");//loads the background image

    public MainMenu(){
        JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();//This is the menu panel, where the main menu is loaded
        menuPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);//set the background color to black
        String menu = "Menu Panel";//name the card or something
        menuPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));
        MainScreen.cardContainer.add(menuPanel, menu);//add the card to the panel
        MainScreen.cardCombo.addItem(menu);//add the item??

        MainScreen.cardLayout.show(MainScreen.cardContainer, menu);//choose what card to show. For this instance show the mainmenu

        paint(null);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        g2.finalize();
    }
}
```

And this is the error I am getting when running the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MainMenu.paint(MainMenu.java:34)
    at MainMenu.<init>(MainMenu.java:29)
    at MainScreen.main(MainScreen.java:37)
```

### ******EDIT******

I removed the line

```
paint(null);
```

When i run the program no error messages shows but the background is not drawed. Only a black background appears.
Full edited file:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MainMenu extends JComponent{

    Image background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("data/images/title.png");//loads the background image

    public MainMenu(){
        JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();//This is the menu panel, where the main menu is loaded
        menuPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);//set the background color to black
        String menu = "Menu Panel";//name the card or something
        menuPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));
        MainScreen.cardContainer.add(menuPanel, menu);//add the card to the panel
        MainScreen.cardCombo.addItem(menu);//add the item??

        MainScreen.cardLayout.show(MainScreen.cardContainer, menu);//choose what card to show. For this instance show the mainmenu
    }

    public void paintThis(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        g2.finalize();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html

Comment: `paint(null);` did you see this?

Answer (score 2):

What did you expect to happend when you call

```
paint(null);
```

at the end of the constructor?

Leave the paint calls to the event dispatcher thread. And don't just put `null` there when you don't know what to use (and then don't be surprised to get a `NullPointerException` when putting `null` into random methods)

Comment: I was trying to call the method paint. I am still learning java and eclipse told me to put null in the parentheses so that was what I did. Please tell me what to do instead.

Comment: Remove the line. And don't program by accepting eclipse suggestions. It lists possible way to make things *compile*, but will usually not solve the underlying error.

Comment: Thanks, will do. But would you please consider helping me with the problem? the program still does not draw the background picture and just because I am a beginner in java I am not a moron. I do know that eclipse can't write the code for me, so I tried what i suggested hoping it would solve it. It clearly did not and so I made this post in hope of help. Up until now I have only received critic on trying so please be kind and help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Well, edit your post to show what your new problem is... and learn how to read errors, because the `paint(null)` was as obvious as they can get!

Comment: I will. I have now edited my post. Thanks.

Comment: Try to get a different color, so you know what it is painting.

Comment: Changed the background to red, no change the image is not being drawed. If it is of any assistance <a href="http://i.imgur.com/vECNd.png">this</a> is the image I am trying to draw.

Comment: why did you rename the method to `paintThis`? It must be called `paint` (and it should be marked as `@Override`).

Comment: I didn't know paint was a built in method I named it randomly so I tried renaming it, thought it might help. It didn't. I named it back and added @Override. Still nothing.

Comment: Well, use a **Tutorial**. It seems you are missing the very basics. Such as: how to paint a custom component.